# Headings of 2nd abstract page in KOMA

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, abstract

I'm writing my thesis with scrartcl, using the KOMAoption `abstract=true`. My abstract has two pages, and while on the 1st page, the pagestyle is empty, on the 2nd page of the abstract all the additional elements (headsepline, footsepline, page number, heading) are shown. The whole text of the abstract is written within the `abstract` environment. Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{scrartcl}

\KOMAoptions{titlepage=true, abstract=true}

\usepackage[automark]{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings} 
\chead[]{}
\ihead[]{}
\lehead[]{}
\ohead{\headmark}
\setheadsepline{.6pt}
\setfootsepline{.6pt}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\title{My Thesis}
\author{It's me}
\maketitle

\thispagestyle{empty}
\addsec{Plagiarism Statement}
I'm not a plagiarist     \newpage

\begin{abstract}    
\lipsum
\end{abstract}

\end{document}
```

I'd like the second page of the abstract to have the same layout as the first one (probably keeping the headings would be better, but I'm not sure yet). I don't understand why the pages are different now as the abstract text is enclosed within the same environment. Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `\pagestyle{scrheadings}` after `end{abstract}` and you will get no headings for the title and abstract pages.

If you want to get headings at the abstract page you can patch the environment `abstract` with `\etoolbox`:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd\abstract{\titlepage}%
  {\titlepage
    \thispagestyle{scrheadings}%
   \markboth{\abstractname}{\abstractname}%
 }{%
  \typeout{*******patching \string\abstract\space done*******}%
 }{%
  \typeout{*******patching \string\abstract\space fails*******}%
}
```

The command `\markboth` is need to get the correct heading.

```
\documentclass[oneside]{scrartcl}

\KOMAoptions{titlepage=true, abstract=true}

\usepackage[automark]{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings} 
\chead[]{}
\ihead[]{}
\lehead[]{}
\ohead{\headmark}
\setheadsepline{.6pt}
\setfootsepline{.6pt}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd\abstract{\titlepage}%
  {\titlepage
    \thispagestyle{scrheadings}%
   \markboth{\abstractname}{\abstractname}%
 }{%
  \typeout{*******patching \string\abstract\space done*******}%
 }{%
  \typeout{*******patching \string\abstract\space fails*******}%
}


\begin{document}



\title{My Thesis}
\author{It's me}
\maketitle

\thispagestyle{empty}
\addsec{Plagiarism Statement}
I'm not a plagiarist
\clearpage
\begin{abstract}    
\lipsum
\end{abstract}
\section{foo}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: The problem aren't the headings after the abstract. The problem is that the first page of the abstract has an empty style, while the second page of the abstract has headings. Adding `\pagestyle{scrheadings}` before `begin{abstract}` doesn't add headings to the first page of the abstract, while adding `\thispagestyle{empty}` before `\begin{abstract}` doesn't remove the headings on the second page. So no matter what I add before the beginning of the abstract, the two pages remain different. (btw: I changed the mwe using lipsum, thanks for the hint)

Comment: @AnjaM: Do you want a header at the first page?

Comment: I am tempted to keep the header on both pages. However, if it's not too difficult, I would prefer to try out both options to see what looks better at the end.

Comment: @AnjaM: I edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks, the one with etoolbox works! Could you please explain why you need the typeout commands? However, the second suggestion (to use `\pagestyle{scrheadings}` after `end{abstract}` ) didn't remove the headings from the second page of the abstract.

Comment: @AnjaM: Of course if you remove `pagestyle{headings}` from the preamble. The command `typeout` prints it's contents into the log-file. So you can see if the patching worked.

Comment: I did remove `\pagestyle{scrheadings}` but I didn't remove the other settings as well. Transferring all the specifications of the heading together with `\pagestyle{scrheadings}` to a place after the abstract solved the problem. Thanks for your help!